# CSS-only hover over thumbnail to display div

Tags: javascript, html, css, selector

I am attempting a simple way of using CSS only to display images within an element, when you hover over their corresponding thumbnail div. I thought this would be relatively easy using the tildie (~) to target the element outside of the thumbnail:hover scope, as both of them would be in the parent container, however it doesn't seem to work, I'd rather not use Javascript for this, but if this isn't possible, then so be it, just thought I'd see what anyone else's input is on this and maybe it can help someone in the future.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <!-- Main images -->
  <div class="primary img1">
    <img src="myimage.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="primary img2">
    <img src="myimage2.jpg" />
  </div>

  <!-- Thumbnails -->
  <div class="thumb img2">
    <img src="myimage2.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.primary.img1 {
  display: block;
}

.primary.img2 {
  display: none;
}

.primary.img2:hover, .primary.img1 {
  display: none;
}

.primary.img2:hover, .primary.img2 {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: A little confusing, what are you trying to do? `.primary.img2:hover ~ .primary.img2 ` I fail to see the point of that also...

Comment: @Ruddy Hovering over the thumbnail for img2, displays it... it is hidden by default. Hovering over that thumbnail also hides img1, so img2 will display in place of it (larger image).

Comment: @RickHitchcock I believe I have a misunderstanding as to what the tildie does then, I thought it could select another element within the parent of the current element?

Comment: @RickHitchcock I disagree. Please check my answer.

Comment: @RickHitchcock But the .container element is their parent?

Comment: @RickHitchcock You are not hiding the `img`, you are hiding the `img` parent which **has** the parent `.container`. You are thinking about the images inside, but we are not hiding them specifically.

Comment: I misunderstood.  I now see that it's the `div`s being hovered instead of the `img`s.  I'll remove my responses.

Comment: For the simplest solution, you'll have to move the markup for your thumbnails above the markup for your main images. Maybe something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ninty9notout/wsbupckm/

Comment: @ninty9notout Thank you very much for that, you should add it as an Answer. I didn't realize you could only target items lower within the parent element. This works and I'll have to just work on something to display the thumbnails below I suppose. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that thumb is after the images you want to display. If you look up the selector you are using then you will understand why.

> The ~ combinator separates two selectors and matches the second element only if it is preceded by the first, and both share a common parent.

[General sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

So as you can see now we can get it working by putting `.thumb` infront. (a little change to the CSS so when we hover `.thumb` it displays the new image.)

```css
.primary.img1 {
  display: block;
}
.primary.img2 {
  display: none;
}
.thumb.img2:hover ~ .primary.img1 {
  display: none;
}
.thumb.img2:hover ~ .primary.img2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <!-- Thumbnails -->
  <div class="thumb img2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  </div>

  <!-- Main images -->
  <div class="primary img1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/351x150" />
  </div>
  <div class="primary img2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/352x150" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's quite wrong what you are doing here because although you have a container that is `.primary` your img clases should be on the images instead . Second of all you cannot hover over display: none elements . Display none removes the element from the page it's not like visibility: hidden; (element invisible but still there in the structure) .So basically you are hovering `.primary.img2:hover` which you gave display: none and making `.primary.img1` display: none . Don't really get what you are trying to ... but i'll show you a structure that i hope it helps .

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <!-- Main images -->
  <div class="primary">
    <img class="img1" src="myimage.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="primary">
    <img class="img2" src="myimage2.jpg" />
  </div>

  <!-- Thumbnails -->
  <div class="thumb">
    <img class="thumb-img2" src="myimage2.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.primary .img1 {
  display: block;
}

.primary .img2 {
  display: block;
}

.img2:hover .img1 {
  display: none;
}

.img2:hover .img1 {
  display: block;
}
```

Hope it helps you somehow ...

Comment: At no point did I say I was hovering over any of the hidden elements?